# Wait for function to finish before executing the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user refreshes the page, `defaultView()` is called, which loads some UI elements. `$.address.change()` should execute when `defaultView()` has finished, but this doesn't happen all the time. `$.address.change()` cannot be in the `success:` callback, as it's used by the application to track URL changes.

```
defaultView();

function defaultView() {
    $('#tout').fadeOut('normal', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "functions.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: "defaultview=true",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#tout').html(response).fadeIn('normal');
            }
        });
    });
}

$.address.change(function(hash) {
    hash = hash.value;
    getPage(hash);
});
```

I'm at a loss as to how to make `$.address.change()` wait for `defaultView()` to finish. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't do this. You've got two asynchronous events going on here: the fadeOut of #tout, and the AJAX request. A synchronous AJAX request is the least desirable piece of Javascript code I can think of. The only way of doing this is to put `$.address.change()` in the success callback of the AJAX request, so another approach is needed.

Comment: `async: false,` is there by error - I was trying how it affected the script. Didn't make any difference, and I removed it.

Answer (score 3):

Call it in the `success` or `complete` callback. Using `delay` for timing a callback is unreliable at best. You might even need to put the call to it in the callback to the `fadeIn` function inside of the `success` callback.

It doesn't have to be defined inside the success callback, just executed. Both contexts will still be able to use it.

Comment: hasn't Wurlitzer said " $.address.change() cannot be in the success: callback "

Comment: Alex, $.address.change() can't be in the success callback, sadly. It is part of this plugin: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ which tracks hash changes every time a link is clicked.

Comment: That is the only solution. It's asynchronous programming 101. You should likely be using a more recent hash history plugin like jquery BBQ. Even with address, you can make a call to the address change in that callback. Just write the code for it...

Answer (score 2):

I too was told that because of async you can't make javascript "wait"  -- but behold an answer :D  ...and since you're using jQuery, all the better:

use jQuery's bind and trigger.  I posted an answer to a similar problem at [How to get a variable returned across multiple functions - Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531080/how-to-get-a-variable-returned-across-multiple-functions-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to hide the $.address (I'm guessing this is a drop-down list) via css, and show it inside the success callback from the ajax method.